# Underlining in LyX Line that Contains Displaystyle

Tags: math-mode, lyx, text-decorations

Is it possible to underline a line in LyX that contains both LyX regular text, and things written in `math-mode`, such that the whole line would have underline positioned in the default distance, but from the vertically-longest character(s)?

Like in here - written in MathType (though in the equation editor):
[image]

Comment: Here is the LaTeX that LyX currently produces:  `\uline{This is a test $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)$}`. That will help others answer your question.

Comment: Actually when LyX 2.3 is released the new LaTeX code produced will be: `\uline{This is a test \mbox{$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)$}}`. Note that it still produces output that is not what you want.